# How to use scipy.optimize.minimize with a variable number of constraints

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a function `equilibrate` (here, `function_to_optimize`) that I want to minimize with respect to as many as four parameters. But, which parameters are optimized should be based on user input. I am using tkinter, and if a user puts a value in the corresponding text box, that parameter should be held constant in the optimization.

A reduced example of my most recent attempt is as follows:

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
from functools import partial

def function_to_optimize(self, k1=18000, k2=3000, k3=2, k4=1, threshold=0.000000001):
    some stuff

def fit_data(self, k1=None, k2=None, k3=None, k4=None):
    to_opt = ()
    csts = ()
    if not k1:
        k1 = self.default_val['K1']
        to_opt += (k1,)
    else:
        csts += (k1,)
    if not k2:
        k2 = self.default_val['K2']
        ...
    ...
    optfunc = partial(self.function_to_optimize, csts)

    result_1 = opt.minimize(optfunc, to_opt, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-7, bounds=((0.1, None), (0.1, None), (0.1, None), (0.1, None)), options={'maxiter': 6000})
```

However, when I try to do this, I get:

`TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

when `function_to_optimize` calls a math operation on some of these parameters. What I think is happening is that the minimizer is passing the arguments in as a tuple, and the function is reading those values as a tuple instead of a float maybe.

I have also tried passing this in as `opt.minimize(self.function_to_optimize, to_opt, args=csts, ...)`, but I get a list of tracebacks ending in:

```
line 788, in _mi    if np.any(lower_bound > x0) or np.any(x0 > upper_bound):
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,)
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? Or is there something syntactic that I am missing here?

Comment: Don't give your end user too much control.  Note that `minimize` (as with most `scipy` functions) is :in-control when if comes to dictating the function signatures and array inputs (shapes, dtype etc).  The more you try to make things "easier" for your end users, the more work you make for yourself.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for the advice. I will try to follow this. Although, in this case the end users are me and my boss. Would it make more sense, then, to write a bunch of similar functions that take different combinations of parameters with separate minimizer functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code above, but let me first suggest this approach:

```py
import scipy.optimize as opt
from functools import partial

# the argument to function_to_optimize will be a numpy array
def function_to_optimize(self, K, threshold=0.000000001):
    k1, k2, k3, k4 = K
    ...

def fit_data(self, k1=None, k2=None, k3=None, k4=None):
    bounds=[[0.1, None], [0.1, None], [0.1, None], [0.1, None])

    if not k1:
        k1 = self.default_val['K1']
    else:
        bounds[0] = (k1, k1 + 1e-7)

    if not k2:
        k2 = self.default_val['K2']
    else:
        bounds[1] = (k2, k2 + 1e-7)
    ...
    ...
    # Partial is not helping here (the parameters cannot be arbitrary, you would need to build a dictionary)
    # optfunc = partial(self.function_to_optimize, csts)

    result_1 = opt.minimize(optfunc, [k1, k2, k3, k4], method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-7, bounds=bounds, options={'maxiter': 6000})
```

Comment: That is genius! Thank you very much. Partial felt wrong, but I also couldn't think of a specific reason why it shouldn't work. I didn't know the parameters could not be arbitrary.

Comment: @ConnorAllen, you can make a partial application with arbitrary parameters, but this was not the correct syntax. You would declare `csts = dict()`, add values with `csts["kx"] = kx_val` and call partial as `partial(f, **csts)`.